# React native view container with different top and bottom background color

Tags: user-interface, react-native, react-redux, reactjs

Trying to create a view with soft border. The header should have a different color and the footer to have a different color. I tried all the possibilities but couldn't figure out. At the moment i have the below code which creates a view with soft border and i want to achieve this.

[image]

```
<View style={{borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10, padding: 10}}>
      <View>
            <Text style={styles.name}>
                SECTOR REPORTS
            </Text>
            <Button title="ADD SECTOR REPORT"/>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `overflow: hidden` on container view, but it's only works on iOS.

overflow:hidden is not supported on Android

check this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3198)

if you want to achieve this on Android, you can use these style props on header and footer components

- `borderTopLeftRadius`
- `borderTopRightRadius`
- `borderBottomRightRadius`
- `borderBottomLeftRadius`

here is an example: [demo](https://snack.expo.io/Sya_zmUfb)

Comment: Thank you DMoon. Ended up using borderTopLeftRadius, borderTopRightRadius, borderBottomRightRadius, borderBottomLeftRadius

Comment: I wonder who would downgrade my question. It was a genuine question and I did try it before I posted it here so it was not like i was blindly looking for answers. :)

Comment: I guess it's because the question is not clear enough. I think `the child view is not clipped to the shape of the parent` is better.